# Can I use WHERE with table field on right side of LIKE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, h2, sql-like

I have a SQL table that contains prefixes of strings that I would like to match against longer strings. Suppose the column containing the prefix is called `prefix`.

I now want to do a simple search for all rows that prefix a longer string. My first thought is to use a query that is something like this:

```sql
SELECT prefix FROM Prefixes WHERE 'long string' LIKE prefix%
```

The point in question is how I get the WHERE clause right. How can I tell SQL to use the value in column `prefix` as a prefix for my argument `'long string'`?

And can I also tell SQL to not only use the column 'prefix' as a prefix for `'long string'`, but instead check whether `'long string'` contains `prefix` anywhere within itself?

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT prefix FROM Prefixes WHERE 'long string' LIKE %prefix%
```

If vendor-specific things play a role here, I am using JDBC to run the queries and my database is either H2 or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concatenation to generate the string that contains the value of the column `prefix` with the wildcard(s):

```
SELECT prefix FROM Prefixes WHERE 'long string' LIKE prefix || '%'
```

If you want to *check whether 'long string' contains prefix anywhere within itself*:

```
SELECT prefix FROM Prefixes WHERE 'long string' LIKE '%' || prefix || '%'
```

You could also use the function `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT prefix FROM Prefixes WHERE 'long string' LIKE CONCAT(prefix, '%')
```

or:

```
SELECT prefix FROM Prefixes WHERE 'long string' LIKE CONCAT('%', prefix, '%')
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c59746011e1c5385be2844394a9e764a).